# Running a python script that is stored on a server, on the current active directory

Tags: python, macos, server

I have a .py script stored on my server. Lets assume the absolute path to this script being

```
\\100.0.0.1\_projects\_topgun\_pipeline\scripts\bin\myscript.py
```

to break a little an explain here I've created a script with the wonderful guidance of people here in my last topic, to copy and create directories based on a file name. However currently users my COPY and PASTE this .py file into the active directory and then run it using terminal / the python launcher.

I would like to make this simpler so I am wondering if there is a way i can allow them to just go to the active directory they wish to run the script one and then just maybe right click invoke a CMD / Terminal menu that gives them options of scripts to run and they can press [1] which runs [myscript.py]

To to list this down systematically:

1. User browsers to a network folder they wish to run the script on
2. They run terminal or cmd which lists all possible scripts to run
3. They input a number based on the script they wish to run
4. Script runs on active directory

If this a complex task to answer I'm more than happy to accept guidance on how to run just the `myscript.py` on the active directory. Also worth noting is this is being built for both mac and windows but mainly windows for now.

Thank you, hoping my question asking skills have improved from my last topic.

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to be able to choose the script:

```
available_scripts = [
  'example.com/1.py',
  'example.com/2.py'
  # and etc.
  ]

# List all scripts available
print('Available scripts:')
for ind, script in enumerate(available_scripts):
  print('[%s] %s' %(ind, script))
print('-' * 20)

# Makes user choose one
script_num =0
while True:
  try:
    script_num = int(input('Enter script number: '))
  except ValueError:
     print('Invalid input, try again')
     continue
  if script_num >= len(available_scripts) or script_num < 0:
     print('Input out of range, try again')
     continue
  break

script_url = available_scripts[script_num]
filename = 'local_' + available_scripts[script_num].split('/')[-1]
```

Now that we have the chosen script, we need to download it:

```
import urllib.request

urllib.request.urlretrieve(script_url, filename)
```

And finally, we need to run it:

```
import subprocess

print('Running script #%s: %s' %(script_num, script_url.split('/')[-1]))
subprocess.run(['python', filename])
```

Also, if you want to clean up after, you should remove the file:

```
import os

os.remove(filename)
```

Comment: i see, why cant they bash SHH to the script and run it off the server why download it ?

Comment: @tankbusta OP wants it to run in the directory, not to run it remotely. I’m essentially automating the copy/paste he talks about.

Comment: Edited answer to actually make urllib work, and I tested it and it works

Comment: im the OP hah!, no i want it to run on the server not on their machines i just want them to call on it but leave all the operations on server side

Comment: @tankbusta oh sorry! Didn’t see you were OP, going to write another answer tomorrow

Comment: @tankbusta hey, actually, I was thinking about your problem, and I was wondering what your script consists of; does it just takes for input a path and then prints: hey, you should create a directory named like this, or does it actually create the directory? Because if it creates the directory, you have to run the script locally (my answer), or rewrite your script so that it sends to local script (the script you use to choose the script) the dir to create, which he will then create, which is possible, but more complicated.

Comment: Hello! well the script looks at files in a directory, the active directory splits the files using os.split('_') and then outputs a folder for each of the splits so a file thats called RRR_0303_v0001.mov will be put into \RRR\0303\v0001\ so it creates these (using makedirs) and then copies it over. I just want to automate this so they can go to a directory and then run the script vs copy pasting it and then running it and then deleting the py file each time in each folder

Comment: @tankbusta ok, I know how to do what you ask, but it requires an external module and requires to change your script and to do the creation part client side, so if the script on the server is a small easy script, then I think it’s best if you go the way to just download the script. But if it is a big heavy script, than it’s profitable.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing for smaller scripts this might be harder than it seems, ok what about expanding the problem is there a way to keep scripts locally but run them on the active folder ?

Answer (score 0):

So, here's how to do a remote script chooser, where the  *stdout* output of the script will be executed locally.

#### File chooser

```
available_scripts = [
    '~/Desktop/test.py', 'path/to/script1.py'
    # and etc.
]

# List all scripts available
print('Available scripts:')
for ind, script in enumerate(available_scripts):
  print('[%s] %s' % (ind, script))
print('-' * 20)

# Makes user choose one
script_num = 0
while True:
  try:
    script_num = int(input('Enter script number: '))
  except ValueError:
    print('Invalid input, try again')
    continue
  if script_num >= len(available_scripts) or script_num < 0:
    print('Input out of range, try again')
    continue
  break

script_path = available_scripts[script_num]
```

---

Now that we have the script chosen, we need to tell it what files are in the *cwd*.

#### ls like thingy

```
import os
files = [
    f for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd())
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), f))
]
```

---

Now, we just need to get an ssh connection.

### **WARNING: THIS REQUIRES THE EXTERNAL MODULE *paramiko*!!**

```
from paramiko import SSHClient
import paramiko
import sys

ssh = SSHClient()

# You should have host keys
ssh.load_system_host_keys() # you can pass a filename
# You choose how to get the password
ssh.connect(server, username=username, password=password)
```

---

Now we use that ssh connection to execute the script and capture the output.
We also pass the files.

#### Remote execution

```
try:
  ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(
    'pytho %s "%s"' % (script_path, files),)
except SSHException as e:
  print('Remote program execution failed:\n' + ssh_stderr)
  print(e)
  sys.exit()
```

---

Now, we execute the output (the file making part in your case)

#### Local execution

```
# Will give us what commands the remote script wants us to execute
commands = ssh_stdout.read().decode('utf-8')

try:
  print('Running local commands...')
  eval(commands)
except Exception as e:
  print('Error while executing local commands: ' + str(e))
  sys.exit()
print('Local commands executed, finished.')
```

---

---

Now what do we have in the remote script? It's pretty easy:

```
import sys
from ast import literal_eval

print('print("huuh")')
print('print(' + str(literal_eval(sys.argv[1])) + ')') # literal_eval will transform '["filename", "filename"]' to a real list
```

The local script will execute what you print.

In your case, what you'd want to do is this:

```
files = literal_eval(sys.argv[1])
commands= 'import os'

for file in file:
  #do stuff
  commands += '\n' + 'os.makedirs(%s)' %(the_name_of_the_dir)
print(commands)
```